# Where to find xampp default 404 page files

Tags: xampp

[screenshots click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cMHx.png)

HI ,Can any one Help me.i am not able to find xampp default 404 pages files.i need to edit those pages. for reference i attached image

Comment: Those default error pages are not separate HTML markup files, they are built in. What you can do is register custom pages for that. Take a look into the official documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: Thanks. its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone else has a similar issue.

If you go to the error/include directory you will see HTML files which you can edit.

Additionally, the error directory contains HTML vars which you can also edit for various errors (i.e. NOT FOUND, FORBIDDEN, UNAUTHORIZED, etc.)

I hope this helps!